# Aligning the items not working as expected

Tags: css, position, display

I need a small help. I've some of the images designed as below. You can see my code here

[`codepen.io/anon/pen/WoEXZN`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WoEXZN)

But I'm not getting the output as expected.

**Reference Design**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**. And include the flex aligning properties to the parent element.

Just like:

```
.wedding-img {
  display: flex; /* Flex Container */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Wrapping Hexagons to next line after a certain width limit is reached */
  justify-content: center; /* Center aligning hexagons horizontally */
  align-items: center; /* Center aligning hexagons vertically */
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below (*use full screen to view it properly*):

```css
.wedding-img {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 103px;
}

.hexagon {
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 260px;
  height: 314px;
  margin: -60px 0 0 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
  margin-top: -103px;
}
.hexagon-in1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
.hexagon-in2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  text-align: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: #f1f4f5;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
  display: table;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wedding-img">
  <div class="hexagon">
    <div class="hexagon-in1">
      <div class="hexagon-in2 groom"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hexagon">
    <div class="hexagon-in1">
      <div class="hexagon-in2 groom"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hexagon">
    <div class="hexagon-in1">
      <div class="hexagon-in2 groom"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hexagon">
    <div class="hexagon-in1">
      <div class="hexagon-in2 groom"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hexagon">
    <div class="hexagon-in1">
      <div class="hexagon-in2 groom"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hexagon">
    <div class="hexagon-in1">
      <div class="hexagon-in2 groom"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hexagon">
    <div class="hexagon-in1">
      <div class="hexagon-in2 groom"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, you answer is closer to my need, but not completely, need a small help again, there is large gap between the first layer (4 hexogons) and the second layer (3 hexogons)

Comment: Perfect Thank you verymuch

Comment: @e-Designary This is because of the transformation of hexagons, you can apply a `margin-top` hack, but this will ruin your responsive design, please have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: @e-Designary Its my pleasure!